# "object github is not a member of package com" for WeKanban2 example project in Scala in action book

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

I'm new in Scala so started from reading "Scala in Action" book 2013 year. But I cannot build plain sbt WeKanban2 project. I use newer version scala and sbt then in example.
I get error when run sbt:

```
error: object github is not a member of package com import com.github.siasia.WebPlugin._
```

my build.properties:

```
//was sbt.version=0.12.0
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

plugins.sbt

```
// was libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-eb-plugin"  (v+"-0.2.11.1")) 
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.7.0")
```

build.sbt

```
import com.github.siasia.WebPlugin._

name := "weKanban"

organization := "scalainaction"

version := "0.2"

//was: scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-unchecked", "-deprecation")

resolvers ++= Seq(
"Scala-Tools Maven2 Releases Repository" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases",
"Scala-Tools Maven2 Snapshots Repository" at "http://scala-tools.org/repo-snapshots"
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-core" % scalazVersion,
  "org.scalaz" %% "scalaz-http" % scalazVersion,
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-servlet" % jettyVersion % "container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % jettyVersion % "test, container",
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-server" % jettyVersion % "container",
  "com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.2.137",
  "org.squeryl" % "squeryl_2.10" % "0.9.5-6"
)

seq(webSettings :_*)
```

build.scala

```
import sbt._
import Keys._

object H2TaskManager {
  var process: Option[Process] = None
  lazy val H2 = config("h2") extend(Compile)

  val startH2 = TaskKey[Unit]("start", "Starts H2 database")
  val startH2Task = startH2 in H2 <<= (fullClasspath in Compile) map { cp =>
      startDatabase(cp.map(_.data).map(_.getAbsolutePath()).filter(_.contains("h2database")))}         

      def startDatabase(paths: Seq[String]) = {
        process match {
          case None =>
            val cp = paths.mkString(System.getProperty("path.seperator"))
            val command = "java -cp " + cp + " org.h2.tools.Server"
            println("Starting Database with command: " + command)
            process = Some(Process(command).run())
            println("Database started ! ")
          case Some(_) =>
            println("H2 Database already started")
        }
      }     

  val stopH2 = TaskKey[Unit]("stop", "Stops H2 database")
  val stopH2Task = stopH2 in H2 :={
    process match {
      case None => println("Database already stopped")
      case Some(_) =>
        println("Stopping database...")
        process.foreach{_.destroy()}
        process = None
        println("Database stopped...")
    }
  }  
}

object MainBuild extends Build {
 import H2TaskManager._
 lazy val scalazVersion = "6.0.3"
 lazy val jettyVersion = "7.3.0.v20110203"

 lazy val wekanban = Project(
   "wekanban",
   file(".")) settings(startH2Task, stopH2Task)}
```

What should I do to fix this error? What should I do to start app from Idea 14 in debug mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import

```
import com.github.siasia.WebPlugin._
```

failed to find path github and below. In your plugins.sbt you wrote:

```
// was libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-eb-plugin"  (v+"-0.2.11.1")) 
addSbtPlugin("com.earldouglas" % "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.7.0")
```

The github-path probably existed in the outcommented com.github.siasia.xsbt-eb-plugin. However the com.earldouglas.xsbt-web-plugin have only the path com.earldouglas.xwp. You should check out if any of the classes there (https://github.com/earldouglas/xsbt-web-plugin/tree/master/src/main/scala) resembles what you need to import.

Comment: you are right. And I found it just after sending error. I try "import com.earldouglas._" and it is better. Now I faced issue "unresolved dependency:...". So I have to change "resolvers". On What if I need "libraryDependencies" above. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Probably not related exactly to this package but similar. The library was present in sbt and everything looked ok. But I still was unable to build the project so I went to my `$HOME/.ivy2/cache` located the dependency directory and deleted it, then went back the `$PROJECT_HOME/` and executed `sbt build`